# trying to contourplot deviation but it is not giving output or error

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to have contourplots of deviation dc for variables a and b.

```
In[27]:= \[Alpha]1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
r_] := -(a^2*(1 + l)*(2*M + 2*r + b) + 
  r*(2*r^2 + 3*b*r + b^2 - 2*M*(3*r + b)))/((a*
   Sqrt[1 + l]*(2*M - 2*r - b))*Sin[\[Theta]])
```

```
In[28]:= \[Beta]1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_, r_] := 
 Sqrt[(r^2*(8*a^2*(1 + l)*
         M*(2*r + b) - (2*r^2 + 3*b*r + b^2 - 2*M*(3*r + b))^2)/((1 + 
          l)*a^2*(2*M - 2*r - b)^2)) + 
   a^2*Cos[\[Theta]]^2*(1 + l) - \[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r]^2*
    Cos[\[Theta]]^2]
```

```
In[29]:= re1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_] := 
 RankedMax[
  r /. NSolve[{\[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r] == 0, r > 0}, r, 
    Reals], 1]
```

```
In[30]:= pr1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_] := 
 RankedMax[
  r /. NSolve[{\[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r] == 0, r > 0}, r, 
    Reals], 2]
```

```
In[31]:= xc1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_] := 
 NIntegrate[\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r]*\[Beta]1[l, b, 
     a, \[Theta], M, r]*D[\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], r], {r, 
    pr1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M], re1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M]}]/
  NIntegrate[\[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r]*
    D[\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], r], {r, 
    pr1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M], re1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M]}]
```

```
In[32]:= R[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
  r_] := (\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r] - 
     xc1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M])*
   D[\[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], r] - \[Beta]1[l, b, 
    a, \[Theta], M, r]*D[\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], r]
```

```
In[33]:= raverage[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_] := 
 Sqrt[(1/\[Pi])*
   NIntegrate[
    R[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], {r, re1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M], 
     pr1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M]}]]
```

```
In[34]:= R1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
  r_] := ((Sqrt[(\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r] - 
           xc1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M])^2 + \[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], 
          M, r]^2] - 
      raverage[l, b, a, \[Theta], 
       M])^2)*(((\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r] - 
         xc1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M])*
       D[\[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], r] - \[Beta]1[l, b, 
        a, \[Theta], M, r]*
       D[\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], 
        r])/((\[Alpha]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r] - 
         xc1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M])^2 + \[Beta]1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M,
         r]^2))
```

```
In[41]:= dc1[l_, b_, a_, \[Theta]_, 
   M_] := (1/raverage[l, b, a, \[Theta], M])*
   Sqrt[(1/\[Pi])*
     NIntegrate[
      R1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M, r], {r, re1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M], 
       pr1[l, b, a, \[Theta], M]}]];
```

```
In[43]:= ContourPlot[
 ConditionalExpression[dc1[0, b, a, 17*\[Pi]/180, 1], 
  Im[dc1[0, b, a, 17*\[Pi]/180, 1]] == 0], {b, 0, .42^2}, {a, .001, 1}]
```

```
Out[43]= $Aborted
```

The code calculates the average radius of a parametric curve and then find the deviation of the curve from circularity in terms of rms value. the last line is not giving any output neither giving any error.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your code simply may be slow.  Have you tried evaluating `dc1` for typical values of `a` and `b` to see whether the results are reasonable and the computations not too slow?  Repeated calls to `NIntegrate` could consume a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

α1[l_, b_, a_, θ_, M_, 
  r_] := -(a^2*(1 + l)*(2*M + 2*r + b) + 
     r*(2*r^2 + 3*b*r + b^2 - 2*M*(3*r + b)))/((a*
      Sqrt[1 + l]*(2*M - 2*r - b))*Sin[θ])

β1[l_, b_, a_, θ_, M_, r_] := 
 Sqrt[(r^2*(8*a^2*(1 + l)*
         M*(2*r + b) - (2*r^2 + 3*b*r + b^2 - 2*M*(3*r + b))^2)/((1 + l)*
        a^2*(2*M - 2*r - b)^2)) + 
   a^2*Cos[θ]^2*(1 + l) - α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r]^2*
    Cos[θ]^2]

re1[l_, b_, a_, θ_, M_] := 
 RankedMax[
  r /. NSolve[{β1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] == 0, r > 0}, r, Reals], 1]

pr1[l_, b_, a_, θ_, M_] := 
 RankedMax[
  r /. NSolve[{β1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] == 0, r > 0}, r, Reals], 2]
```

Since `xc1` uses a numeric technique, restrict its arguments to being numeric.

```
xc1[l_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r]*β1[l, b, a, θ, M,
      r]*D[α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], r], {r, 
    pr1[l, b, a, θ, M], re1[l, b, a, θ, M]}]/
  NIntegrate[β1[l, b, a, θ, M, r]*
    D[α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], r], {r, pr1[l, b, a, θ, M], 
    re1[l, b, a, θ, M]}]
```

Define `R` using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` so that the derivatives are only done once.

```
R[l_, b_, a_, θ_, M_, 
   r_] = (α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] - xc1[l, b, a, θ, M])*
    D[β1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], r] - β1[l, b, a, θ, M, 
     r]*D[α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], r];
```

Since `raverage` uses a numeric technique, restrict its arguments to being numeric.

```
raverage[l_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ, 
  M_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[(1/π)*
   NIntegrate[
    R[l, b, a, θ, M, r], {r, re1[l, b, a, θ, M], 
     pr1[l, b, a, θ, M]}]]

R1[l_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ, 
  r_] := ((Sqrt[(α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] - 
           xc1[l, b, a, θ, M])^2 + β1[l, b, a, θ, M, 
          r]^2] - 
      raverage[l, b, a, θ, 
       M])^2)*(((α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] - 
         xc1[l, b, a, θ, M])*
       D[β1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], r] - β1[l, b, a, θ, 
        M, r]*
       D[α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], 
        r])/((α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] - 
         xc1[l, b, a, θ, M])^2 + β1[l, b, a, θ, M, r]^2))

dc1[l_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ, 
  M_?NumericQ] := (1/raverage[l, b, a, θ, M])*
  Sqrt[(1/π)*
    NIntegrate[
     R1[l, b, a, θ, M, r], {r, re1[l, b, a, θ, M], 
      pr1[l, b, a, θ, M]}]]
```

It takes more than 5 seconds to calculate a single value for the plot.

```
ConditionalExpression[dc1[0, b, a, 17*π/180, 1], 
   Im[dc1[0, b, a, 17*π/180, 1]] == 0] /. {b -> 0, 
   a -> 0.001} // AbsoluteTiming

(* {5.47811, 1.23194*10^-7} *)
```

To control the number of calculations, generate a [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) of data and use [`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html)

```
n = 9;

(plotData = Flatten[Table[
      {b, a, ConditionalExpression[
        dc1[0, b, a, 17*π/180, 1],
        Im[dc1[0, b, a, 17*π/180, 1]] == 0]},
      {b, 0, (42/100)^2, (42/100)^2/n},
      {a, 1/1000, 1, (999/1000)/n}], 1];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {635.234, Null} *)

ListContourPlot[plotData,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {b, a}), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Re "Can't I use ContourPlot so that the plot becomes continuous coloured instead of lines separating them? " Look at the documentation for [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html). `ContourPlot` looks just like [`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html), i.e., contour lines with [`ContourShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html). Perhaps you meant to ask about [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) or [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html).

```
ListDensityPlot[
 plotData, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {b, a}), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: When I define R using set , the script is running . It doesn't end

Comment: Can't I use ContourPlot so that the plot becomes continuous coloured instead of lines separating them?

Comment: thanks for your answer and reply. But when I define R using set the script is running. It doesn't stop

Comment: You say you changed `R`; did you run all of the code I posted above? What version are you running? I used v12.3 to produce the posted results.

Comment: Now the code is running fine. Thank you Bob

Comment: while trying different inputs i am getting this  `n = 9;
(plotData = 
    Flatten[Table[{a, \[Theta], 
       ConditionalExpression[dc[0, 0, a, \[Theta]*\[Pi]/180, 1], 
        Im[dc[0, 0, a, \[Theta]*\[Pi]/180, 1]] == 0]}, {a, 1/1000, 
       1, (999/1000)/n}, {\[Theta], 1/100, 90, (8999/100)/n}], 
     1];) // AbsoluteTiming
i am getting too many errors. I am using version 12.0

Comment: "i am getting too many errors" What errors? Also, the code in your comment uses the function `dc`; however, that is undefined. The posted code uses the function `dc1` Before plotting, first make sure that the argument of the plot evaluates to a numeric value for a set of values in the plot range.

Comment: Run the code you gave for l=0,b=0 for values of a from 0 to .95 and theta from 0 to pi/ then you will get many errors. Don't know how to tackle them

Comment: Look at the error messages and analyze what is causing them. For example, `α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] /. a -> 0` and `α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] /. θ -> 0` and `α1[l, b, a, θ, M, r] /. θ -> Pi` indicate why some of the errors occur. If you are unable to resolve the other errors, post a new question showing what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: I have posted a new question with some modifications